# Apple Pay on Blueprint themes

Tags: bigcommerce

Is a theme modification necessary for blueprint themes in order to properly provide support for apple pay or is it provided through the %%GLOBAL_AdditionalCheckoutButtons%% variable?

Comment: https://support.bigcommerce.com/articles/Public/Integrating-the-Apple-Pay-button#style includes the CSS you need in order to fully get this working in BP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the apple pay button with **white bg/black text**, you need to add the following css:

```
.apple-pay-checkout-button {
  background-image: -webkit-named-image(apple-pay-logo-black);
  background-color: white;
}
```

For **black text/white bg**:

```
.apple-pay-checkout-button {
  background-image: -webkit-named-image(apple-pay-logo-black);
  background-color: white;
  border: .5px solid black
}
```

The necessary html and integrations bits are already there with the variable you mentioned