# What are the specs for the CSS function -webkit-named-image()?

Tags: css, function, webkit

I was just browsing [**this stylesheet**](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/assets/storefront/additional-checkout-buttons-e666b0b8a20c90d1eaafcc0f38897f2b4ab8af21f68426b37926e48a2ae452c2.css) when I noticed a CSS function I have never encountered before: **-webkit-named-image()**

I did some digging and found links on SO [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39573965/apple-pay-on-blueprint-themes/39577977#39577977) and a developer page [**here**](https://developer.apple.com/reference/applepayjs/applepaysession). The only apparently-valid arguments for this function that I can find are `apple-pay-logo-black` and `apple-pay-logo-white`, e.g.:

```
div { background-image: -webkit-named-image(apple-pay-logo-black) ;}
```

I have lots of questions, for example:

Is this function deprecated or still currently valid? (based on the recency of [**this link**](https://www.hitchhq.com/stripe/activities/apple-pay-on-the-web-57dfb6b07ab5cb2d63b13747) and [**this one**](https://blog.passkit.com/how-to-set-up-apple-pay-on-the-web-for-your-website-stripe/) I assume it is not deprecated). Are there other acceptable arguments for this function (besides the ones I mentioned above)? Is this function similar to the `url()` function insofar as the passed function argument can be quoted or unquoted? Is it Safari specific?

In brief, *how can I find out more about this function and what are the realistic use cases?*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This CSS function is vendor specific, so there is no specification. It's used to display some named images embedded in WebKit.

To discover the valid argument of this function, one solution is to look in the [source code of WebKit](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit). The C++ function associated to this CSS function is [`drawNamedImage`](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/67ae82595fac9135422be694653a119905b3bfa0/Source/WebCore/platform/Theme.h#L111) from the [`Theme`](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/67ae82595fac9135422be694653a119905b3bfa0/Source/WebCore/platform/Theme.h#L46) class.

```
virtual void drawNamedImage(const String&, GraphicsContext&, const FloatRect&) const;
```

There is a comment in the implementation of [`drawNamedImage`](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/67ae82595fac9135422be694653a119905b3bfa0/Source/WebCore/platform/Theme.cpp#L60):

```
void Theme::drawNamedImage(const String& name, GraphicsContext& context, const FloatRect& rect) const
{
    // We only handle one icon at the moment.
    if (name != "wireless-playback")
        return;
```

But each theme can override this function and define its own named images. The [Cocoa theme](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/8ff2aef949f9fb1857fe85990d8c5c831b99d872/Source/WebCore/platform/cocoa/ThemeCocoa.mm#L108) define the values `wireless-playback`, `apple-pay-logo-black` and `apple-pay-logo-white`.

There is yet, no other theme in the source code of WebKit, that define named images.

Answer (score 1):

-webkit-named-image() CSS  generator allows a site to request artwork by name and get the platform variant and recently being added to webkit.

Check this bug which got resolved some time back
https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=164235

Currently what I know Safari now ships with built-in images which we can use with -webkit-named-image().

As per stripe documentation:

> Step 2: Add an Apple Pay button to your site
>   Start by adding a button to the HTML on your product page. Safari now >ships with built-in Apple Pay images; you can use them with Safari's ->webkit-named-image feature. This button should be hidden by default.

I think this is being done to create uniform style across internet.